# Setting a UISwitch in a UITableViewCell triggers other UISwitches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiswitch

I'm using different prototype-cells in my uitableviewcontroller. It works fine, except when I'm using UISwitches. If I use many UISwitches and switch a switch, other Switches are also switched.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSDictionary *dict;
    if (indexPath.row > 0) {
        dict = [self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        int nr = [[dict objectForKey:@"typeid"] intValue];
        if (nr == 1) {
            //cell with in texfield
        } else if (nr == 2)  {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"switch";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.ficheTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];    
            cell.textLabel.text = @"";
            [self createLabelWithCell:cell tag:1 dict:dict valuekey:@"label" indexpath:indexPath];

            UISwitch *switch1 = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            switch1.tag = [[dict valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
            switch1.accessibilityIdentifier = @"value";
            switch1.on = NO;

            if ([dict valueForKey:@"value"] != [NSNull null]) {
                if ([[dict valueForKey:@"value"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                    NSLog(@"%ld %@",(long)switch1.tag, [dict valueForKey:@"value"]);
                    switch1.on = YES;
                }
            }

            [switch1 addTarget: self action: @selector(flipSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            return cell;
        } else if (nr == 3) {
            //cell with a textfield number only
        }
        ...
}

- (IBAction)flipSwitch:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *switch2 = (UISwitch*)sender;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *aValue;
    NSString *tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)switch2.tag];
    NSString *userid = [userDefaults stringForKey:kuserid];
    if (switch2.on) aValue = @"1"; else aValue = @"0";

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                switch2.accessibilityIdentifier,@"field",
                                tag,@"id",
                                aValue,@"value",
                                @"BLABLA",@"appcode",
                                userid,@"userid",
                                @"updatefichenr", @"command",
                                nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:appDelegate.baseURLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }];
}
```

If I read the tag in flipSwitch of lower placed UISwitches I also get the tag of other UISwitches.

I already looked at similar problems here but I didn't find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. If your table view cells are dynamic(Value Changes based user action), then you need to take a custom cell class. Need to give outlets to the subviews. In cell for row give

```
swith.tag = indexpath.row;
```

With this tag, you can reload the particular cell.

Comment: What do you mean with "reload the particular cell"?